# Java: convert an EnumSet to a primitive array E[] (usage: JComboBox DefaultComboBoxModel)

Tags: java, swing, collections, enums, set

I have several `JComboBox` with some values dependent from previus selections.

All my jComboBox are typed like that:

```
JComboBox<E> comboBox
```

And i can create a nice `DefaultComboBoxModel` with a single method that works perfectly:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E> & MyEnumInterface> JComboBox<E> createCompleteJComboBox( final Class<E> clazz, boolean startsDisabled) 
    {
        JComboBox<E> comboBox = new JComboBox<>();
        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(clazz.getEnumConstants()));
        comboBox.insertItemAt(null, 0);
        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
        comboBox.setEditable(false);
        comboBox.setEnabled(!startsDisabled);
        return comboBox;
    }
```

Then I have some JComboBox i want to fill with only few Enums in a previously created `EnumSet`, like this:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E> & MyEnumInterface> void applyCustomValueList2(JComboBox<E> comboBox, final Set<E> allowedValues)
    {

//      List<E> llist = new ArrayList<E>(allowedValues.size());

        boolean hasAnyValue = allowedValues == null ? false : true;
        int size = hasAnyValue ? (allowedValues.size() + 1) : 1;

        if (hasAnyValue)
        {
            List<E> sl = new ArrayList<>(allowedValues);
            E[] enumComboItems = (E[]) allowedValues.toArray();
            comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(enumComboItems));

        }


        comboBox.setEnabled(hasAnyValue);
    }
```

**But I'm unable to transform EnumSet allowedValues in a primitive E[].**

---

EDIT:
Error i get

```
09:32:01:625 [ERROR] ( AWT-EventQueue-0) (XXXController.java:208) - uncaught exception in thread AWT-EventQueue-0:[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Enum;
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Enum;
    at xyz.xzad.asdasd.asdasd.ComboCreator.applyCustomValueList2(ComboCreator.java:74)
    at xyz.xzad.asdasd.asdasd..Panel$MyItemChangeListner.itemStateChanged(PanelSettingsAnagraphics.java:975)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(JComboBox.java:1225)
```

---

Had a try with previous example, passing by `Collections` and `Arrays.asList` but I'm doing something wrong.

Any idea?

I'll prefer to not use any wrapper class inside DefaultComboBoxModel.

Thank you in advice

Comment: Add them one at a time using the addItem(...) method of the JComboBox.

Comment: why the downvote ?

Comment: In what way are you *"unable to transform EnumSet `allowedValues` in a primitive `E[]`"*? The statement you have works fine: `E[] enumComboItems = (E[]) allowedValues.toArray();`

Comment: @Andreas illegal cast. Maybe I'm declaring something wrong with generics

Comment: @Andreas At runtime, `toArray()` will return an `Object[]`.

Comment: @chrylis And at runtime, `E[]` is an `Object[]` too, because of type-erasure, since `Object` is the only common type between `Enum<E>` and `MyEnumInterface`, isn't it? Of course, it would help if the **question showed the exact error message**, so we all know what is going on.

Comment: @Andreas This is why I need caffeine.

Comment: Got it, forget to paste the error and trace. I'll update tomorrow, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new E[]
```

implied by

```
        E[] enumComboItems = (E[]) allowedValues.toArray();
```

will because of type erasure give an `Object[]`.

Either add the items one by one, or go retro:

```
        Vector<E> enumComboItems = new Vector<>(allowedValues);
        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(enumComboItems));
```

This would also be solvable by keeping the enum class as runtime field, parameter to the constructor.

Comment: thank you so much. I didn't noticed constructor with Vector, this saves my day :)  (And thanx a lot for explication about erasure)

Comment: Error message indicates that `E[]` means `Enum[]`, not `Object[]`, which is causing `(E[]) allowedValues.toArray()` to throw that error, so problem could also have been fixed using `(E[]) allowedValues.toArray(new Enum[allowedValues.size()])`, but I think using `Vector` is a better solution.

Comment: @Andreas `toArray` can only create an `Object[]` as at  runtime from E only remains Object. The general solution would be to use the other parametrized `toArray(new MyClass[sl.size()])` with a concrete class. Not possible here.

Comment: `Enum` is a concrete class, and according to error message, that is what is expected: *"ClassCastException: `[Ljava.lang.Object;` cannot be cast to `[Ljava.lang.Enum;`"* which in human terms mean *"ClassCastException: `Object[]` cannot be cast to `Enum[]`"*. That error means that `E[]` is type-erased to `Enum[]` such that `(E[]) allowedValues.toArray()` becomes `(Enum[]) allowedValues.toArray()`. That's the only way for that particular exception to be thrown.

Comment: @Andreas good formulation, and helpful. The compiler indeed creates a cast to `Enum[]` for the assignment, but `toArray` can only deliver `Object[]` - there is no `new Enum[]` involved.

Comment: @JoopEggen Sure there is. See my first comment: `allowedValues.toArray(new Enum[allowedValues.size()])`

Comment: @Andreas OK, but that would still not be strongly typed, `Enum[]` is not an `E[]`. I would add a type parameter to the constructor, and indeed a parameter to the `toArray`

Comment: @JoopEggen Which is why using `Vector` is much better, because there is no need to know what type-erasure is applied, and no use of generic arrays, so no use of raw generics. `Vector` is simply the *right way* to do this, and why I up-voted your answer. My first comment was just to show that you *could* do it with arrays, if you do it right, not that you *should* do it that way.

Comment: @Andreas contribution really appreciated; a coin has three sides to bet on - one never knows.